# Search suggestions not working in SharePoint 2013

Tags: search, 2013

I have made sure search suggestions are enabled, as per the kb http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj721441.aspx, however when I go to Enterprise Search centre and start typing, no suggestions drop down.

I can confirm search is crawling files, as searching for terms and hitting enter yields correct results.

I have also tried 4 or 5 times the same search term, but no luck.

Any ideas on what to try next?

Comment: I have the same issue. From reading around the last couple of days on this, I am now looking at the Analytics side of this. I will update if I get anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

That article suggests that...."By default, the search system automatically creates suggestions for a query when users have clicked the results for that query at least six times."

I have verified that that works... remember **the link that the search term returns** MUST be clicked at least six times..... (**the same link**) before that term becomes a suggested search term....

Then, when you begin to type that same term, a suggestion will appear under the search box. Additionally, on the results page, that link that you clicked six times will be shown saying something to the effect that... "you have viewed this link in relation to this search term" (paraphrasing but you'll see what I mean)

I haven't tried the *Query Suggestion Settings* page but will when I have a chance... I'll let you know if I'm successful.